# where does the file saved after you create it in terminal?

Tags: command-line, scripts, files

I created a script that create a file with the command `touch`
in which directory the file saved?

The script is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
touch abc.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

If you give `touch` no path but only a filename, it creates the file in the current directory. In the terminal you can **p**rint the **w**orking **d**irectory with `pwd` or by looking at your prompt, which displays it by default. In case of a script the file gets created in the directory the script was started in – provided you didn't use `cd` to **c**hange the **d**irectory in the script before.

Comment: thank you!, but for some reason i cant see the file in the current directory

Comment: hope its good now :)

Comment: @SnirSudri Works fine for me – did you make it executable with `chmod +x SCRIPTNAME`? Please try this chain of commands (which do the whole job in one line): `echo -e "#\!/bin/sh\ntouch abc.txt" >test.sh; chmod +x test.sh; ./test.sh; ls` This should output `abc.txt test.sh`.

Comment: yes i did but it doesn't create

Comment: with your command it's worked but why the regular command didn't work?

Comment: @SnirSudri Please edit your question and show what exactly you did, only then we can say what you did wrong. :)